# Hamiltonian Structure of Chern Simons Electrodynamics

Tags: gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, chern-simons-theory, poisson-brackets

I am reading the review paper "Aspects of Chern-Simons Theory" by Gerald Dunne

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902115

Starting from p. 17, Dunne works on the Hamiltonian structure of the CS electromagnetism. When there is no Maxwell term, the CS action is given by

$$L = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{ij} \dot{A}_i A_j + A_0 B\tag{70}$$

where I set $\kappa = 1$, and this is given in his equation 70. The conjugate momenta is then

$$\Pi^i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{A}_i} = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{ij}  A_j\tag{73}$$

which can also be found in his eq. (66) given that $e \rightarrow \infty$. The equal-time canonical commutation relations is then given by

$$\left[A_{i} (x) , \Pi^j (x) \right] 
= i \delta^j_i \delta^{2} (x-y)\tag{68}$$

which is given in his eq. (68). Then, he uses the definition of the conjugate momenta and finds that

$$\left[A_{i} (x) , A_j (x) \right] = i \epsilon_{ij} \delta^{2} (x-y).\tag{72}$$

I do not know how to get this result. Now let me write down what I got

\begin{equation}
\left[A_{i} (x) , \Pi^j (x) \right] = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{jk} \left[A_{i} (x) , A_k (x) \right]
\end{equation}

On the other hand, since $\left[A_{i} (x) , \Pi^j (x) \right] = i \delta^j_i \delta^{2} (x-y)$, we have

\begin{equation}
i \delta^j_i \delta^{2} (x-y) = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{jk} \left[A_{i} (x) , A_k (x) \right]
\end{equation}

Multiplying each side by $2 \epsilon_{jm}$ and using $\epsilon^{jm} \epsilon_{jn} = \delta^m_n$, i obtain
\begin{equation}
\left[A_{i} (x) , A_j (x) \right] = 2 i \epsilon_{ij} \delta^{2} (x-y)
\end{equation}

Apparently i am missing a factor of 2, but i have no idea what i do wrong.

Comment: I used Dirac bracket but i still got the same result. It is actually just plugging in some definition into an equation, isn't it. What could i possibly i do wrong? does he have a weird definition of $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon^{ab} \epsilon_{bc} = 2 \delta^a_c$?

Comment: my struggle is simpler than the degree of freedom counting. it is just going from one equation to the next one by plugging in some definition. i cannot even pass that point. How to get rid of the factor of 2 in A,A commutator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no factor of 2. The Dirac-Bergmann analysis$^1$ goes as follows. The second-class constraints are
$$ \chi^i ~=~\pi^i - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ij} A_j, \qquad i~\in~\{1,2\}. $$
The matrix of Poisson brackets$^2$ of second-class constraints is
$$ \Delta^{ij}(x,y)~:=~\{\chi^i(x),\chi^j(y)\}~=~-\epsilon^{ij}\delta^2(x-y), $$
so the inverse matrix is
$$ (\Delta^{-1})_{ij}(x,y)~=~-(\epsilon^{-1})_{ij}\delta^2(x-y). $$
The [Dirac bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket) becomes
$$ \{A_i(x),A_j(y)\}_D~=~-(\epsilon^{-1})_{ij}\delta^2(x-y). $$

References:

1. G.V. Dunne, [arXiv:hep-th/9902115](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902115).

--

$^1$ Ref. 1 implicitly mentions between eqs. (70)-(71) a shortcut via the [Faddeev-Jackiw method](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306075).

$^2$ To go from brackets to commutators, multiply with $i\hbar$.